# Is the primary identifier of an Active Directory user the 'logonname' attribute?

Tags: active-directory

For security purposes, is the primary identifier of  an Active Directory user the 'logonname' attribute?

For example a user with the logonname "bob" is first created then removed from AD, then an another user is created again with the logonname "bob" - is this new user, from a security perspective, equivalent?

The reason I ask this question is due to some recent peculiarities with opening a PST mailfile - as the above example, a user has been removed then recreated with the same loginname, this new user is not permitted to open the previous users pst file despite sharing the same username.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the objectSid (a [SID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier)) is the primary ID when it comes to assigning permissions.  A new user with the same name will have a different objectSid, and therefore will not be able to access files which the original user had permission to.

Comment: ZING! An answer in less than 10 minutes - I love this forum.

Thanks Sean!